# I've an error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'leave' of undefined'

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've a problem. I've install ytdl-core for my discord bot, but, when the bot has to automatically leave the vocal room, I get this error:

```
console.log(queue);
        (function play(song) {
            console.log(song);
            if (song === undefined) return msg.channel.send('La file d\'attente est vide').then(() => {
                queue[msg.guild.id].playing = false;
                msg.member.voiceChannel.leave();
```

The error :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'leave' of undefined
```

Honestly I do not think it's a problem of definition ..

Comment: I see a *method* call `.leave()` in `msg.member.voiceChannel.leave();`, but not a *property* read `.leave`. Could you post the full error message including the stack trace, and a longer cut of your code including the line where the error originated from? Perhaps you have an old `console.log` lying around somewhere that's causing this issue?

Comment: @Cloud A method is actually a property of an object.

Comment: To debug this, ask yourself: where did `msg` come from?   Where did `msg.member` come from?  And finally where did `msg.member.voiceChannel` come from?  Ultimately, you will discover that `msg.member.voiceChannel` is undefined, and the browser can't access the property `leave` of `undefined` -- just like it says.

Comment: Ah thanks @slothiful, apologies, still learning here :) I was expecting the error to say something about a method instead, and thought that it saying "Cannot read property" meant that the error originated from a `.leave` somewhere else (and not from the `.leave()`).

Answer (score 2):

`msg.member.voiceChannel` is undefined. That means that the user isn't in a voice channel. Before trying to use it, ensure the property (`voiceChannel`) exists.

```js
const voiceChannel = msg.member.voiceChannel;

if (voiceChannel) {
  voiceChannel.leave()
    .catch(console.error);
}
```